# How to observe key value for NSUserDefault initWithSuiteName so you can Send and Possibly receive data from iOS App to WatchKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am trying various solutions to send/receive data from iOS App to WatchKit App.

Tried MMWormhole didn't work, so trying the following.

In ViewDidLoad:

```
mySharedDefaults = [[NSUserDefaults alloc] initWithSuiteName: kGROUP_SUITE_NAME];

[mySharedDefaults addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timeLeft" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld) context:NULL];
```

and:

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                 ofObject:(id)object
                   change:(NSDictionary *)change
                  context:(void *)context
{
// NSLog requires a formatting string as its first arg
// NSLog(keyPath);
NSLog(@"observeValueForKeyPath: keyPath=%@", keyPath);
NSLog(@" object=%@", object);
NSLog(@" text=%@", [object valueForKey:keyPath]);
}
```

I call this in the app:

```
NSString *timeLeft = @"00:00";
    [mySharedDefaults setObject:timeLeft forKey:@"timeLeft"];
```

I have found this code for Swift, what is the Objective-C equivalent?

// write

```
let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupName)
sharedDefaults?.setInteger(1, forKey: "myIntKey")
```

// read

```
let sharedDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: appGroupName)
let myIntValue = sharedDefaults?.integerForKey("myIntKey")
```

I really want to read only when write happens (i.e.: observing value changes ).

I have added App Groups ( in iOS App ) and made sure the is exists in target ( WatchKit App )

Answer (score -1):

You can't reliably KVO a shared userDefaults. Use [MMWormhole](https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMWormhole) instead. MMWormhole uses the Darwin Notification Center to alert changes between the extension and the main app.

Comment: Sorry, I said in the post that I had already tried MMWormhole and it did not work.

Comment: @MikeZriel I'm happy to help. CFNotificationCenter is probably the only way.